# Can I create multiple queues of same type in RabbitMQ in a way that publishing message on channel is not duplicated on other queue of same type?

Tags: rabbitmq, message-queue, rabbitmq-exchange

I am looking for two queues with same binding key , but not getting duplicate messages (i.e. the message goes to any one queue, but not both). Ultimate goal of not duplicating messages is to achieve the load balancing such that if queue one has messages in it then next message should be published to queue two [Image showing the messages routing to queues](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kyixe.jpg)

Is this possible in RabbitMQ? Is there any library on top of RabbitMQ.CLient that implements it? Is there any built in mechanism to handle the load in queues?

Currently, I'm using EasyNetQ library for RabbitMQ.Client.

Comment: To my knowledge, there is no way to do what you describe, nor does it make sense, as the "load balancing" aspect should typically be achieved by having multiple consumers on the same queue